# How to print "<" in HTML tag?

Tags: html

I want to print `#include <stdio.h>` in `<code>` tag:

```
<code>#include <stdio.h></code>
```

But the above code outputs only `#include`, no `<stdio.h>`:

```
#include
```

How can I print "<" in HTML tag?

Comment: write as follows: &lt;stdio.h&gt

Comment: `<code>#include <<x>stdio.h></code>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Escape it http://www.freeformatter.com/html-escape.html#ad-output

```
&lt;code&gt;#include &lt;stdio.h&gt;&lt;/code&gt;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with `&lt;` and `&gt;` 
`#include <stdio.h>`