# Some htaccess code not appearing within HTML <code> and <pre> elements

Tags: html, pre

I have the following code

```html
<pre>
  <p style="margin:0;font-weight:bold;padding:5px;">HTACCESS Test</p><hr>
  <code>
<FilesMatch "^\.">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
  </code>
</pre>
```

As you can see when running the code, the `<FilesMatch "^\.">` and `</FilesMatch>` lines do not appear. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30775190/how-to-print-in-html-tag

Comment: I totally forgot about that, thanks so much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print "<" in HTML tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30775190/how-to-print-in-html-tag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others looking for a solution, you need to escape HTML characters when using them in within `<pre>` and `<code>` tags.